# How to multiply every combination of elements of two vectors and output in a third vector?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-365

I need a function or combination of functions which would be able to perform the following operation:

Given two vectors containing booleans (might be integers as well):
V1 = {0;1}
V2 = {1;0;1}

I want to generate a third vector which would contain the product of all combinations of v1 and v2 elements:

V3 = {V1[1]*V2[1];V1[1]*V2[2];V1[1]*V2[3];V1[1]*V2[2];V1[2]*V2[2];V1[2]*V2[2]}

or, for my example:

V3 = {0;0;0;1;0;1}

I need the output this way so that I can perform this operation iteratively with more than 2 sets.

Alternatively, if anyone knows how to convert a matrix to vector in formulas like "=M2VEC(A1:C3)" (M2VEC being usable within formulas) I think that would also solve my problem since I could just multiply V1 and V2^T (transposed) and then convert to vector. Which would render the same result.

I prefer using vector functions from Excel 365.

Comment: It's been years since I used these functions, but there is matrix calculations in excel. For example `=MINVERSE()` . Maybe start searching for that function and it will take you where you need to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given two **vertical** arrays *Vector1* and *Vector2*,

`=LET(x,ROWS(Vector1),y,ROWS(Vector2),z,SEQUENCE(x*y,,0),INDEX(Vector1*TRANSPOSE(Vector2),1+INT(z/y),1+MOD(z,y)))`

will produce the desired third **vertical** array.

Comment: Thank you, that solves it!